# How can you load multiple JQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

How can you load multiple JQuery plugins that use the `$` to access methods? My configuration file (`config.js`) is as follows:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery",
        "jqueryui": "lib/jquery-ui",
        "semanticui": "lib/semantic",
    },
    shim: {
        "jqueryui": {
            exports: "$",
            deps:['jquery']
        },
        "semanticui": {
            exports: "$",
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }};
```

My application file (`load.js`) is defined as follows:

```
define(['jqueryui', 'semanticui'], function ($) {
    console.log($);
})
```

I found that the `$` was undefined. However when I use the following code below:

```
define(['semanticui', 'jqueryui'], function ($) {
    console.log($);
})
```

`$` is defined as the `jQuery` object.

Is it possible to use the `$` to access jQuery and the methods defined by the plugins?

This is the `index.html` file I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/app.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
    <script data-main="load" src="lib/require.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
        <div class="ui fluid container">
            <div class="header item" id="activateSidebar">AthenaViz<i class="terminal icon"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END OF NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <!--SIDEBAR MENU-->
    <div class="ui left vertical  sidebar labeled icon menu">
        <a class="item">
        </a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Visualize
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--END OF SIDEBAR MENU-->
    <div class="pusher">
<table class="ui striped table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date Joined</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Called</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Lilki</td>
      <td>September 14, 2013</td>
      <td>jhlilk22@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jamie Harington</td>
      <td>January 11, 2014</td>
      <td>jamieharingonton@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill Lewis</td>
      <td>May 11, 2014</td>
      <td>jilsewris22@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>Jill Lewis</td>
      <td>May 11, 2014</td>
      <td>jilsewris22@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td>Jill Lewis</td>
      <td>May 11, 2014</td>
      <td>jilsewris22@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The addition of your index.html allowed me to trivially duplicate your setup and find the issue very quickly. I did not realize initially the problem was with jQuery UI because the last time I used it (which was not *that* long ago, it seems to me), it did not call `define`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a `shim` with jQuery UI, because it calls `define` by itself, and `shim` is only for modules that do not call `define`. If you look at the [code here](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js), you'll see near the start of the file:

```
(function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define([ "jquery" ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery );
    }
}(function( $ ) {
```

And it looks like the factory function does not return anything, which explains why you got `$` set to undefined.

Semantic UI does need a `shim` because it does not call `define`.

I suggest that instead of trying to grab `$` from the plugins, you get it from `jquery` itself:

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'semanticui'], function($) {
  console.log($);
});
```

The order may appear strange but it will work fine. You have to think about how jQuery plugins install themselves: they modify the jQuery object, which is `$` here. So the code above will load `jquery`, then load `jqueryui`, which will modify jQuery to add itself as a plugin, and load `semanticui`, which will also modify jQuery to add itself as a plugin. (Actually, `semanticui` could load before `jqueryui` because one is not dependent on the other, but it does not change the end result.) So the `$` that you get into your anonymous function will have the plugins installed on it.

I do what I'm suggesting above all the time, without any issue, but I use the CommonJS idiom:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var $ = require("jquery");
    require("bootstrap");
    require("jquery.bootstrap-growl");
});
```

`bootstrap` and `jquery.bootstrap-growl` install themselves as jQuery plugins, but I get my reference from `jquery` itself.

(The CommonJS idiom is not better. It's just what I use.)