# Can not run jqueryui and requireJS correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, r.js

I am loading RequireJS and jQuery UI in `<script>`:

```
<script src="js/require.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jqueryui.js" ></script>
<script src="js/myapp.js" ></script>
```

In myapp.js, I wrote a simple jQuery widget plugin:

```
 $.widget("custom.myComp", {....
```

However, I can never enter the factory function and the console prints out:

> $.widget is not a function

[image]

Like the snapshot shows, the program enters line 10, but never enters line 30, so that I can never use the jQuery UI functions like `$.widget`.

How can I avoid that?

PS: I know I can write the dependencies in the RequireJS config file, 
but the current situation is when i use r.js optimized js files.
Suppose I have merged all js files together.

As demonstrated here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minzojian/3836h4s9/1/)

Make sure to open the browser's JavaScript console before clicking "Run" to see the error from RequireJS.

This [jQUery UI bug](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/13449) describes the same problem, but it looks there is not any solution.

Comment: This problem occurs becuase you're using requirejs. either remove requirejs, or actually use require js, i.e: load jquery, jquery ui  and your script in proper order using requirejs, without the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you load multiple JQuery plugins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095968/how-can-you-load-multiple-jquery-plugins)